# How to correctly use a Workerthread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I've been writing android apps for some months now, and I'm at the point where I'm building an actual needed app.

As I want that to work nice and fast, I made a Workerthread to do all kinds of tasks in the background while the UI can...build up and work and stuff.

It's based on the Android Studio Drawer app blueprint.

In Main.onCreate I got my `operator=new Operator()`, which extends `Thread`.

Now, when loading a new Fragment, it sometimes calls `MainActivity.operator.someMethod()` (I made operator static so I can use it from anywhere), and after some time I realized, the only tasks actually running in background are those in the operators `run()` method and an `Asynctask` my login Fragment runs. Everything else the UI waits for to complete and therefore gets executed by the UI thread.

So I thought: no problem! My `operator` gets a `handler` which is built in `run()`, and I change those tasks:

```
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();   //Android crashed and said I had to call this
    OpHandler = new Handler();
    LoadLoginData();
    [...Load up some Arrays with hardcoded stuff and compute for later use...]
}

public void LoadLoginData() {
    OpHandler.post(LoadLoginDataRunnable);
}
private Runnable LoadLoginDataRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(sharedPreferences==null)
            sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sessionID=sharedPreferences.getString("sessionID", null);
        if(sessionID!=null) {
            postenID = sharedPreferences.getString("postenID", PID_STANDARD);
            postenName = sharedPreferences.getString("postenName", PID_STANDARD);
            context.QuickToast(sessionID, postenName, postenID);
        }
    }
};
```

context is my MainActivity, I gave the operator a reference so I could send Toasts for Debugging.

But now, the Runnables seem to not run or complete, any Log.e or Log.d stuff doesn't arrive in the console.

After some googeling and stackoverflowing, everyone is just always explaining what the difference is between Handlers, Asynctask, and Threads. And the multitask examples always only show something like `new Thread(new Runnable{run(task1)}).start` times 3 with different tasks.

And so became my big question:

**How to correctly, over a longer time (~lifecycle of the MainActivity), with different tasks, use a background thread?**

Edit: to clarify, I would also like a direct solution to my special problem.

Edit 2: after reading nikis comment (thank you), the simple answer seems to be "use HandlerThread instead of thread". Will try that as soon as I get home.

Trying a HandlerThread now. It seems my OpHandler, initialized in `run()`, gets destroyed or something after `run()` has finished, not sure whats up here (this is btw another mystery of the kind I hoped would get answered here). I get a NullpointerException as soon as I try to use it after `run()` has finished.

Comment: I recommend you read [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html) and revisit your code. An `AsyncTask` may not be what you want here. Android's preferred way for a task-queue would be an `IntentService`.

Comment: don't think this is advertisement, but http://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/

Comment: You need to do Looper#loop last in your operator#run method. An other option is to use a [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) instead. Don't forget to quit the thread when you are done.

Answer (score -2):

Make your worker thread own a queue of tasks. In the `run()` method, just pop a task from the queue and execute it. If the queue is empty, wait for it to fill.

```
class Operator extends Thread
{
     private Deque<Runnable> tasks;
     private boolean hasToStop=false;

     void run()
     {
          boolean stop=false;
          while(!stop)
          {
               sychronized(this)
               {
                    stop=hasToStop;
               }
               Runnable task=null;
               synchronized(tasks)
               {
                    if(!tasks.isEmpty())
                         task=tasks.poll();
               }
               if(task!=null)
                   task.run();
          }
     }

     void addTask(Runnable task)
     {
          synchronized(tasks)
          {
               tasks.add(task);
          }
     }

     public synchronized void stop()
     {
          hasToStop=true;
     }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason for the downvote, so that I can upgrade the answer (or at least learn something I don't know).

Comment: Not my downvote, maybe it doesn't tackle my special example or the question why the handler doesn't work.   @topic: so my thread has to run all the time? I hoped I could let my thread work "on demand" so it doesn't need CPU power while not needed, also because it, as mentioned, only sometimes gets a task when I switch fragment or login/logout or some other stuff.

Comment: @Marlon Regenhardt If you expect the thread to stay idle most of the time, just let him sleep a bit at every iteration, so that checks on the queue are less frequent. This should make the overhead of the thread negligible.

Comment: Synchronizing the boolean access does not gain you anything. Also I would recommend using [LinckedBlockingQueue](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) which will take care of most the work. The take() method will bock if the queue is empty.

Comment: I updated my question.  Cyroxis: could I have a coffee snippet example for that? (Preferably using my use case).